# RSA or Paillier is good?

Tags: rsa, homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, file-encryption, paillier

I want to implement file storage in cloud using homomorphic encryption. I want to use paillier encryption. Can you suggest the drawback of RSA to store and retrieving the files. Then only i can use paillier instead of RSA.

Comment: I suspect you have a misunderstanding about what homomorphic encryption with RSA or Paillier achieves. Encrypting files like that is almost certainly not useful.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... @rukshana, are you sure that you want to do some operations (like sum, or multiple) the encrypted files ?

Comment: i want do my project on retrieving the file stored in cloud using homomorphic encryption. I saw that the encryption used in file storage is RSA.But i want to use paillier to store the encrypted file and index in the cloud.Then the autherised user can send encrypted query to server and server perform operation on encrypted index stored and encrypted query received.I think the project on RSA is already implemented. I want to suggest paillier for this purpose. So can anyone suggest any advantage is there by using paillier instead of RSA.Is it possible?